# How to upload files with Vue.js2 and Laravel 5.4?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to upload an image using `Laravel` as a backend and `Vue.js2` as a frontend.

**Here's my code**

```
addUser() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fullname', this.newUser.fullname);
    formData.append('email', this.newUser.email);
    formData.append('phone', this.newUser.phone);
    formData.append('photo', this.newUser.photo);
    formData.append('roles', this.newUser.roles);
    formData.append('permissions', this.newUser.permissions);

    axios.post('users', formData)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
         })
         .catch((error) => {
             console.log(error);
         });
    },

    onFileChange(e) {
        let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        if (!files.length)
            return;
        this.createImage(files[0]);
    },

    createImage(file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        let vm = this;
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            vm.newUser.photo = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
```

**And `Laravel` code on a backend:**

```
if($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Файл есть.',
        'data' => $request->all()
    ]);
}

return response()->json([
    'success' => true
]);
```

**Finally, the html code:**

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-text="Загрузите фото" @change="onFileChange">
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. File has not been found. What's the workaround?

Comment: Steps to diagnose the problem: Did you confirm that the File was attached to the request? Did you confirm the right endpoint was hit on your backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I simply deleted `createImage(file)` method and changed `onFileChange(e)` method like this:

```
onFileChange(e) {
    let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        if (!files.length)
            return;
        this.newUser.photo = files[0];
}
```

And everything worked perfecly. **Thanks for everyone for spending time and help...)**

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the image gets attached to the request sent because the line `formData.append('photo', this.newUser.photo);` only appends the file's temporary url to the formData due to the fact that the property `photo` of the `newUser` object was set to the temporary url of the file inside your FileReader `onload` method: `vm.newUser.photo = e.target.result;`.

You should attach the *file* to the formData and not the *temporary url*

To do that, you might want to change your `createImage(file)` function to:

```
createImage(file) {
   let reader = new FileReader();
   this.newUser.photo = file;
   let vm = this;
   reader.onload = (e) => {
      vm.newUser.photo_preview = e.target.result;
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
```

and you can use `this.newUser.photo_preview` for showing the photo preview wherever you like in your view.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: did u find solution?